# Make instance wait until called functions are complete - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, init

I apologise in advance if this has already been answered but as you can probably tell from the title I wasn't really sure how to describe the issue and a answer to a similar question I found wasn't helpful.

I'm attempting to make an instance of "Coupon" that has its properties loaded from an SQL database after passing an id to the database in the init method.

My issue is when I call then init method from a different viewController class it will return the instance with the default string values of "" as the data from the NSURLConnection hasn't been/decoded before returning to the viewContoller.

Im looking for a solution for to some how make the init method wait until the fields are loaded.

Coupon class relevant properties:

```
var webData: NSMutableData?

var id: Int
var name: String = ""
var provider: String = ""
var details: String = ""
```

Coupon class relevant methods:

```
convenience init(id: Int) {

    self.init()
    self.id = id

    self.selectSQL(id) //passes id to server and returns all other varibles

}

   func selectSQL(id: Int) {

    let url = NSURL(string: "http://wwww.website.php?id=\(id)") // acess php page
    let urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
    let connection = NSURLConnection(request: urlRequest, delegate: self)

}

func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, didReceiveResponse response: NSURLResponse) {

    webData = NSMutableData()

}

func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, didReceiveData data: NSData) {

    webData?.appendData(data)

}

func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection) {

    let result = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(webData!, options: .AllowFragments, error: nil) as? NSArray

    let resultDict = result?[0] as? NSDictionary

    if let dict = resultDict {

        name = dict.objectForKey("name") as! String
        provider = dict.objectForKey("provider") as! String
        details = dict.objectForKey("details") as! String

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to "wait for your SQL finishing" and then return from `init` without blocking your thread (synchronize), which would not be what you want.

I suggest to use a factory method with a callback to get a workaround for it. Like this:

```
class Coupon {
    private var handler: ((coupon: Coupon) -> ())?

    class func createCoupon(id: Int, completionHandler: ((coupon: Coupon) -> ())?) {
        let coupon = Coupon(id: id)

        // Store the handler in coupon
        coupon.handler = completionHandler
    }

    //...

    func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection) {

        //...Setup coupon properties
        handler?(coupon: self)
        handler = nil
    }
}
```

Then you can create and use your coupon like this:

```
Coupon.createCoupon(1, completionHandler: { (coupon) -> () in
    // Do your thing with fully "inited" coupon
})
```

Of course, you also need to consider the situation of connection failed to your server, and maybe call the `handler` with an error, which does not present in your current code.

Comment: Thank you very much! im still wrapping my head around how this works, im just curious why at the end of the connectionDidFinishingLoading func why do we set the handler to nil

Comment: sorry to double post - also when we set the handler?(coupon: self) is this when the actual closure that we passed in from Coupon.createCoupon:: being called

Comment: Here in `class func createCoupon` method,  we created an empty coupon object and set the handler property to store what should be called after the coupon gets the property "fully inited" from your server. And in the `connectionDidFinishLoading`, we called that stored handler to inform the caller that things done. After that, the handler is not needed anymore, so we set it to `nil` to prevent holding unnecessary things. It depends what you write in the completionHandler when calling createCoupon, it might be a retain cycle to prevent the coupon releasing properly.